# ExtJS 4 textfield regex condition

Tags: regex, extjs, textfield

I can't solve simple regex pattern in ExtJS 4 texfield.

I have to enter hour and minute in format "**HHMM**" and I use such a regex:

```
/[012][0-9][0-5][05]$/
```

And it is working almost good> Almost, because it's possible to enter `2900`.
I can't set in this regex that, when the first digit is "2" the second
have to be from 0 to 4 not from 0 to 9.

Be so kind as to prompt me in this case.

Comment: The last [05] means I accept only 5 minites in the end of HHMM.

Comment: Try `^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJ6sG3/2)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])` - two alternatives:

  - `[01][0-9]` - 1 or 0 followed with any one digit
  - `|` - or
  - `2[0-3]` - `2` followed with `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`
- `[0-5][0-9]` - `0` to `5` digit followed with any 1  digit
- `$` - end of string

To include `2400` as a valid match, use

```
^(?:(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]|2400)$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJ6sG3/3)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I started to look in conditional regex definition and thought about such a construction but it eliminete 2400 unfortunately. Valid values have to be from 0000 to 2400. Could I place condition inside condition?

Comment: Use `^(?:(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]|2400)$`. You meant to say add an alternation group into another group of alternatives - yes, you can.

Comment: In the meantime I checked and do it by myself, but anyway thank you again for help

Comment: So, is my answer working for you? I added the above regex to the answer.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for - working perfect.